# Why when I drag something using IDragHandler IPointerEnterHandler not always working on another object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement drag and drop using unity's EventSystem. When I start drag one object using IDragHandler - IPointerEnterHandler on another object doesn't works from time to time. Does someone know how to solve this? Or maybe someone know the reason why this restriction existing?

Answer (score 1):

Since EventSystem works with raycasting, there may be another object which blocks the ray. So, you should make sure there is no other object that may block raycasts.

If you are using dragging for UI elements you can change other objects CanvasGroup to canvasGroup.blocksRaycast = false or you can set it as lastSibling https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetAsLastSibling.html.

If you are doing it with gameObjects you can change your object's layer to something higher from others. Such as 10. But do not forget to make it default again when you are done with it.

If you can share a gif or something else, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Thank you! That is what am I looked for!

Comment: There is another problem - I changed the object's layer (where I wanted to execute IPointerEnterHandler), but IPointerEnterHandler starts working only when the cursor leaves the object's rederer for the first time. Before that, he leads like in the previous case, after that everything is ok

Comment: To make it clear, is it working after you clicked for the first time to the game scene?